# Como arrumar uma UL(estilizada) que quebra dentro da DIV?

Tags: html, css

Eu sou novo na área de design, e estava tentando montar uma página como esta http://www.anamelmercearia.com.br/
Antes de mais nada gostaria de agradecer pela ajuda, pois tentei muito arrumar este problema mas não consegui chegar a solução, e agora entendo o quanto o conhecimento é valioso!

Bem meu problema e a UL na coluna3, quando diminuo a página ela quebra para      baixo e o menu que está ocorrendo invasão de elementos

preciso que nenhum elemento dentro da tanto da caixa como do container quebre ou invada outro em uma largura máxima de 600px, bem pelo que entendi teria que usar media queries, mas de todas formas que tentei deram resultados bizarros...

Código HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Teste Drive</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="author" content="">
   <!--link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/bootstrap.less" type="text/css" /-->
   <!--link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/responsive.less" type="text/css" /-->
   <!--script src="js/less-1.3.3.min.js"></script-->
   <!--append ‘#!watch’ to the browser URL, then refresh the page. -->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400italic,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400italic,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
   <div id="caixa"> 
      <div class="row clearfix">
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" >
              <div class="topo">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-clearfix"style="margin:0 13%">
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="padding:0">
              <div class="altura">
               <div class="coluna1">
                  <ul class="sociaistopo">
                     <li><a class="pinterest" href="http://br.pinterest.com/anamelgourmet">p</a>
                     </li>
                     <li><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Ana-Mel-Mercearia/363119460524421?fref=ts">f</a>
                     </li>
                     <li><a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/anamelmercearia">t</a>
                     </li>
                     <li><a class="instagram" href="https://instagram.com/anamelgourmet/">i</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <p class="cadastro">Faça
                     <a href=""> <span class="cd">loguin</span>
                     </a> ou<a href=""><span class="cd"> cadastre-se</span></a>
                  </p>
               </div>
               <div class="coluna2">
                  <a class="logo" href="#">L</a>
               </div>
               <div class="coluna3">

                  <ul class="navegacao">
                     <li><a class="navega" href="#">home</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="separador">|</li>
                     <li><a class="navega" href="#">meu cadastro</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="separador">|</li>
                     <li><a class="navega" href="#">meus pedidos</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="separador">|</li>
                     <li><a class="navega" href="#">fale conosco</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>

                  <span class="carrinho"><b>meu carrinho</b> <a class="btn2 btn-primary btn-large">0 Item(s)</a><span> 
                </div>
         </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="container1-fluid" style="margin:0 13%">
      <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:-24px">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
          <div class ="menuloja"> 
                <div class="dropdown1">
                  <ul class="listas">
                    <li class="opcoes"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon1 glyphicon-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="nomemenu">REFEIÇÕES</span></a> 
                         <ul class="listas">
                            <li class="opcoes"><a class="nomemenu1 "href="#">MASSAS</a> 
                            <li class="opcoes"><a class="nomemenu1 "href="#">ENLATADOS</a>          <!-- MUDA COR E FONT E NO SPAN-->
                            <li class="opcoes"><a class="nomemenu1 "href="#">SOBREMESAS</a> 
                          </ul> 
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
                  <div class="dropdown1">
                  <ul class="listas">
                       <li class="opcoes"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon1 glyphicon-glass" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="nomemenu">BEBIDAS</span></a> 
                         <ul class="listas">
                            <li class="opcoes"><a class="nomemenu1 "href="#">VINHOS</a> 
                            <li class="opcoes"><a class="nomemenu1 "href="#">SUCOS</a>          <!-- MUDA COR E FONT E NO SPAN-->
                            <li class="opcoes"><a class="nomemenu1 "href="#">IMPORTADOS</a> 
                          </ul> 
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
                  <div class="dropdown1">
                  <ul class="listas">
                       <li class="opcoes"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon1 glyphicon-gift" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="nomemenu" style="marign-bottom:4px">PRESENTEAR</span></a> 
                         <ul class="listas">
                            <li class="opcoes"><a class="nomemenu1 "href="#">UM AMIGO</a> 
                            <li class="opcoes"><a class="nomemenu1 "href="#">UM FAMILIAR</a>          <!-- MUDA COR E FONT E NO SPAN-->
                            <li class="opcoes"><a class="nomemenu1 "href="#">ALGUÉM ESPECIAL</a> 
                          </ul> 
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
                </div> 
                       <div id="area-form">
                         <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control3" placeholder="BUSCAR" required autofocus> <a class="btn3  btn-large">  
                          <span class="glyphicon2 glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                       </div>  
           </div> 
       </div>
      </div>     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
Código CSS

/*ESTRUTURA*/
body{
  background-color:#EAE4D6;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  width: 100%
}
.topo{
    height: 26px;
}
.altura{
    height: 170px;
    display: flex;
}
.altura > .coluna1 {
 width: 33.33%;
 height: 170px;
}
.altura > .coluna2 {
 width: 33.33%;
 height: 170px;
}
.altura > .coluna3 {
 width: 33.33%;
 height: 170px;

}
.fundo{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 200px;
}
.coluna2{

    text-align: center;
}
.coluna3{
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: none;
}
#caixa{
  height:214px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
/*COLUNA1*/

.sociaistopo{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sociaistopo li{
  display:inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.pinterest{                                             /* Criar links com background*/
    background-image:url("../img/pinterest.png");
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:30px;
    float: left;

  }
.facebook{
    background-image:url("../img/facebook.png");
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:34px;
    float: left;
    margin-left:5px;
  }
  .twitter{
    background-image:url("../img/twitter.png");
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:32px;
    float: left;
    margin-left:5px;
  }
  .instagram{
    background-image:url("../img/instagram.png");
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:32px;
    float: left;
    margin-left:5px;
  }
  .cadastro{
    margin-top:40px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #3E332F;
  }
   .cadastro a:hover{
    color: #9D2E2D;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
   .cd{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #8B151B;
  }
/*COLUNA2*/

  .logo{
    background-image: url("../img/logo.png");
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width:193px;
    height: 138px;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }


/*COLUNA3*/
.navegacao{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

 }
 .navegacao li{
   padding: 0;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
   color: #3E332F;
   margin-left: 1%;
   display: block;
  }
  .navega{
    color:#3E332F;
  }
.navegacao li a:hover{ 
   padding: 0;
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#9D2E2D;
  }

/*MENU*/
.menuloja{
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #3E332F;
  display: flex;
}
.nomemenu{
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #EAE4D6;
}
.nomemenu:hover{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.nomemenu1{
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #EAE4D6;

}
 .nomemenu1:hover{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #9D2E2D;
  background-color: 
}
.glyphicon1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #EAE4D6;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.dropdown1{
  float: left;
}
.listas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  }
.listas .opcoes {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #EAE4D6;


  }
.opcoes .listas {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 80;

  }
.listas .opcoes a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EAE4D6;
  background: #3E332F;
  padding: 9px 5px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 17px;

  }
.opcoes:hover .listas {
 display: block;

}
 .opcoes .listas .opcoes .nomemenu1:hover{
   background-color:#9D2E2D;
   color: #FFFFFF;

}
.form-control3:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #AAA7A6;
  font-style: italic;
}

.form-control3::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #AAA7A6;

}

.form-control3:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #AAA7A6;
}

.form-control3::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #AAA7A6;
}

.form-control3 {
  display: inline;
  width:280px;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 16px 0 0 80px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #AAA7A6;
  background-color: #3E332F;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border:1px solid #635954; 
  border-radius:1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;         
}
.form-control3:focus {
  border-color: #635954;
  outline: 0;

}
.btn3 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin:16px 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 26px;
  font-weight: normal; 
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #3E332F;  
  background-image: none;
  border:1px solid #635954; 
  border-radius:1px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
       -o-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.btn3:focus {
  outline: thin dotted #333;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.btn3:hover,
.btn3:focus {
  color: #3E332F;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #3E332F;
}
.carrinho{

  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #3E332F;
  float: right;
  margin-top:9%; 
}


  .btn2{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #9D2E2D;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 124px;
  height: 42px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
       -o-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;

}
.btn2:hover,
.btn2:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #9D2E2D;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.btn2:focus {
  outline: thin dotted #9D2E2D;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Desculpa colocar o código css deste jeito porem, não estava conseguindo colocar outro bloco de código

Comment: complicado, ou você estende seu menu, deixando uma rolagem horizontal na tela, ou você coloca os itens um abaixo do outro, ou diminui a fonte para tamanhos menores, ou um vai invadir o outro como ta acontecendo... voce ainda pode diminuir o padding dos itens, visando melhor aproveitamento de tela, mas, não vejo uma forma lógica de 3 itens ocuparem o mesmo lugar no espaço sem sobrepor ou quebrar linha. Caso não tenha entendido a pergunta, poderia explicar melhor....

Comment: se perceber no exemplo que passou, quando a tela é diminuída, o tamanho da barra do menu se mantém, criando a barra horizontal de rolagem